# How to put application in sleep mode

Tags: android

In order to save power, I want to put my Android application in sleep mode. How can I **manually** put my application in sleep mode?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I manually put my application on the sleep mode ?

Applications do not go into "sleep mode". Devices go into sleep mode.

You cannot manually put a device into sleep mode, as the user may be using it at the time. Please allow the device to fall asleep normally.

> In sleep mode, I know it uses less CPU and RAM.

Applications do not use less RAM when the device is in sleep mode. The device's CPU is powered down (or put into a low-power state) during sleep mode, but, again, this is a characteristic of a device, not of an application.

Comment: I wonder ; are there background jobs mode for an application on the Android ? In linux, as you may know, there are background and foreground jobs. Do Android have them in it ?

Comment: @coler'e: The foreground is what the user sees. The background is what the user does not see. That is the same as it is for every operating system, AFAIK.

Comment: How to put my application to run as background ?

Answer (score -1):

You can now put apps to sleep on Android. Depending on what kind of sleep you put them this may prevent them from updatind, running in the background and / or sending notifications.

To put an app into sleep mode, you go to:

> Settings > Battery and device care > Battery > Background usage limits

Next you will have to decide what kind of sleep you want the app in. After entering the option you've selected, you can tap the plus sign at the top of the screen and select the app you want to put to sleep.

Comment: That may exist on some devices, but it is not universal. In light testing, it appears to be a Samsung thing for newer devices: I see it on the S20, S10, and A50, but not an S8, nor Pixel or Moto phones, for example. If you could please update your question to reflect the scope of this suggestion, I'd be happy to retract my downvote.